# Switch not entering cases but values match

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

I have an issue with the code below. I have a switch statement that isn't entering any of its cases. Say the value of `propType` is "ID", the switch should match this to case "id" but it isn't doing so. What have I done wrong?

```
case "button":
                        Button ctrlButton = new Button();
                        for (int j = 0; j < ctrlProperties.Length; j++)
                        {
                            string currentProperty = ctrlProperties[j];
                            int propDelimiterPos = currentProperty.IndexOf(propDelimiter);
                            string propType = currentProperty.Substring(0, propDelimiterPos);
                            string propValue = currentProperty.Substring(propDelimiterPos + 2);
                            switch (propType.ToLower())
                            {   
                                #region PROPERTY PARAMETERS LEVEL
                                case "text":
                                    ctrlButton.Text = propValue;
                                    break;
                                case "font":
                                    int fontDelimiterPos = propValue.IndexOf(pntDelimiter);
                                    string fontName = propValue.Substring(0, fontDelimiterPos);
                                    string fntSize = propValue.Substring(fontDelimiterPos + 1);
                                    int fontSize = int.Parse(fntSize);
                                    ctrlButton.Font = new Font(fontName, fontSize);
                                    break;
                                case "bounds":
                                    string[] boundsValues = propValue.Split(pntDelimiter);
                                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(
                                                            new Point(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[1])),
                                                            new Size(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[2]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[3])));
                                    ctrlButton.Bounds = bounds;
                                    break;
                                case "id":
                                    ctrlButton.Name = propValue;
                                    break;
                                #endregion
                            }
                            this.Controls.Add(ctrlButton);
                            ctrlButton.Show();
                        }
                        break;
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with the `switch` and examine the variable `propType`. It will not be the value you expect.

Comment: Then i can assume your propType isn't "ID".

Comment: @AntP: read the question. The code is calling `.ToLower`; it's not a casing issue.

Comment: @AntP he's having a ToLower() there.

Comment: May be there are no property type "id" in currentProperty.  you could print out the property type to console before calling the switch to see the value that is being switched.

Comment: Button class do not have an ID property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had already debugged it and propType did have the value ID. @Shrivallabh has resolved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to extra space in your string try this `propType.Trim().ToLower()`

Comment: Good point. User input may contain funny characters, including tabs and newlines.